# Possible to "split" an ActiveAdmin resource between multiple menu items?

Tags: activeadmin

Is it possible to register a resource multiple times, perhaps under different namespaces or scopes?

What I'm trying to achieve:  I have a resource called an "EventDate" -- EventDates can be of several types, say, a birthday party or a dinner party.

Right now I'm doing something very un-DRY ... I have BirthdayParty & DinnerParty both inheriting from EventDate, and I have two separate resources registered in ActiveAdmin.  But both resource pages basically have the same functionality.  So when I make changes to one, I have to make the identical changes to the other.

What I'd much prefer to do is use a single EventDate resource and split that into separate menu items -- one for BirthdayPartys (i.e. EventDate scoped so type = BirthdayParty) and one for DinnerPartys - and when I make changes to their index, show, etc., I only have to do it once.

Is this possible in the ActiveAdmin framework?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can try to use active admin scopes, like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register EventDate do

  # Create sections on the index screen
  scope :all, :default => true
  scope :dinner_party
  scope :birthday_party

end
```

this will make tabs under the breadcrumbs and u'll be able to switch scopes and you won't need the child models in this way. will it work for you?